# jplayer is not working on android 2.3

Tags: android, jplayer

i am having problem playing mp3 in android 2.3 versions.. here is the output of android 2.3.3 emulator after play clicked... setTimeout also not working.. can anybody suggest what is th problem ? Its urgent..

```
02-08 11:58:57.572: E/MediaPlayer(346): error (-38, 0)
02-08 11:58:57.641: E/MediaPlayer(346): Error (-38,0)
02-08 11:59:08.020: I/StagefrightPlayer(34): setDataSource('http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/75945507/stream')
02-08 11:59:08.050: I/NuHTTPDataSource(34): connect to api.soundcloud.com:80/tracks/75945507/stream@0
02-08 11:59:08.460: I/NuHTTPDataSource(34): connect to ak-media.soundcloud.com:80/wrNNoFGzAVBu.128.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4IAZE5EOI7PA7VQ&Expires=1360325086&Signature=lpyyWSCue7wClheAiMdHH3CgD9M%3D&__gda__=1360325086_b4fb6b6ef6022109e33fa20abe103845 @0
02-08 11:59:11.801: I/NuCachedSource2(34): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
02-08 11:59:15.160: D/AudioSink(34): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
02-08 11:59:18.952: W/AudioTrack(34): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x166a8 user=00003000, server=00000000
02-08 11:59:22.509: W/AudioTrack(34): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x166a8 user=00003000, server=00000000
02-08 11:59:26.032: W/AudioTrack(34): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x166a8 user=00003000, server=00000000
02-08 11:59:29.495: W/AudioTrack(34): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x166a8 user=00003000, server=00000000
02-08 11:59:32.982: W/AudioTrack(34): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x166a8 user=00003000, server=00000000
02-08 11:59:36.471: W/AudioTrack(34): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x166a8 user=00003000, server=00000000
02-08 11:59:39.941: W/AudioTrack(34): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x166a8 user=00003000, server=00000000
02-08 11:59:43.410: W/AudioTrack(34): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x166a8 user=00003000, server=00000000
```